# Starting programs using c++ pipe in linux

Tags: c++, linux

I start programs from a C++ program in linux as follows:

```
char* cmd = "/bin/snmpd &";             // command to execute
FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");           // pipe to command line
if (!pipe) return -1;                   // check if pipe worked
pclose(pipe);                           // close pipe
return 1;                               // return
```

Now that starts snmpd, but, the problem is, when this C++ program closes, snmpd closes with it. How do you start a linux program from another C++ program without program being started being dependant on the program starting it?

Comment: Did you try [system](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system)?

Comment: The http://pstreams.sf.net/ code shows how to use `fork` and `exec` to create a new process, rather than using `popen`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're starting the program, you're telling the system
that all output from the program to standarrd out should go into
a pipe to your program.  A pipe which you then close.  Writing
to a pipe which was closed causes a `SIG_PIPE`; unless the
program you start does something special with this signal, it
will be terminated.

If you're not interested in the output from the program, you
should use the standard function `system` to start it:

```
system( "/bin/snmpd &" );
```

should do the trick in your case.  (`system` will start
a subshell, and wait for the subshell to finish, but the `&`
means that the subshell won't wait for `snmpd` to finish.)

Depending on what you are doing, you may want to "demonize" the
process you start, deconnecting it from your process group, so
that it won't be killed even if you log off.  I'm less sure
about this (I've always done it at a lower level), but I think
just redirecting standard out and standard error (and maybe also
standard in) to use `/dev/null` should do the trick:

```
system( "/bin/snmpd < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 &" );
```

Answer (score 2):

If `popen` doesn't do exactly what you want, don't use it. Instead, use `pipe`, `fork`, `exec`, `daemonize`, `setsid`, and so on to implement exactly the behavior you want. Look at an [example `popen` implementation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~eweiss/222_book/222_book/0201433079/ch15lev1sec3.html) for a starting point.